# Remove rows in which string contains other letters than A,C,T,G,N

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I'm fairly new to `numpy` and `pandas`, let's say that I have a 2D numpy array and I need to delete all rows in which the second value contain only the letters `'A'`, `'C'`, `'T'`, `'G'` and `'N'`

```
file = 
[['id' 'genome'],
 ['0' 'ATGTTTGTTTTT'],
 ['1' 'ATGTTTGTXXXX'],
 ['2' 'ATGDD2GTTTTT']
]
```

so after filtering I can get this

```
[['id' 'genome'],
 ['0' 'ATGTTTGTTTTT']]
```

I wanted to do 3 for loops that are checking each char one by one but this is sooo slow when I have 500 rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with values and `^` for start and `$` for end of string:

```
file = [['id', 'genome'],
 ['0', 'ATGTTTGTTTTT'],
 ['1', 'ATGTTTGTXXXX'],
 ['2', 'ATGDD2GTTTTT']
]
 
df = pd.DataFrame(file[1:], columns=file[0])
print (df)


df = df[df['genome'].str.contains('^[ACTGN]+$')]
print (df)
  id        genome
0  0  ATGTTTGTTTTT
```

Comment: when im running this  i get empty dataframe, im running this code on <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: @newDev2000 - What is `print (df['genome'].head(20).tolist())` ?

Comment: nah, it's probably not working because it's numpy.ndarray

Comment: @newDev2000 - So problem convert to DataFrame?

Comment: ok, so I've converted my list to dataframe and when im running this code i get "indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)   raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0"

Answer (score 1):

One other option is `str.match` with the same pattern as in @jezrael's answer:

```
df = df[df['genome'].str.match('^[ACTGN]+$')]
```

Also, we can detect the illegal character with negation on `str.contains`:

```
# [^ACTGN] detects any characters that are not ACTGN
df = df[~df['genome'].str.contains('[^ACTGN]')]
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are probably more efficient as they use native pandas functionality. If you're more handy with Python then you can use map to perform the filtering.

```py
df = DataFrame(
    data={
        'id': [0, 1, 2],
        'genome': ['ATGTTTGTTTTT', 'ATGTTTGTXXXX', 'ATGDD2GTTTTT']
    }
)

filtered_df = df[df['genome'].map(lambda x: re.sub('[ACTGN]+', '', x) == '')]
```

In this last line:

- Use map to run a function on each row
- The lambda syntax means: for each value `x` use the function `re.sub('[ACTGN]+', '', x) == ''`
- The `re.sub` function says replace any character in ACTGN with blank.
- After replacing the **known** characters with `''`, if the string is empty then we want to keep the row.

The advantage of this approach is that you can use any python code on the pandas values.

```py
filtered_df = df[df['genome'].map(lambda x: <any-code-you-want-that-yields-a-boolean>)]
```